# Excel VBA 他シートの内容が反映されない

Tags: vba, excel

#### 解決したいこと

Excel VBA 他シートの抽出したデータ内容が反映されない

#### 発生している問題・エラー

他のシートからエクセルシートのデータ抽出を行いたいのですが、‘＝’を用いたデータの反映が行われません。同一セルの中に他のデータを入れているのが問題なのでしょうか。

**実際のコード:**

```
BASEDATE >= TO_DATE(‘元のシート！G7’,‘YYYY/MM/DD’)
```

#### 自分で試したこと

- シングルクォーテーションを外す

どなたか解決の糸口が欲しいです。ご協力お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim BASEDATE As Date
Dim TO_DATE As Date
BASEDATE = #2023/03/31# '日付型の値を代入
TO_DATE = CDate(Sheets("元のシート").Range("G7").Value) '文字列を日付型に変換
If BASEDATE >= TO_DATE Then
    'BASEDATEがTO_DATE以上ならば何らかの処理を行う
End If
```